# What are the possible results for the wheel of misfortune?

Tags: 8-bit-waterslide

In *8-Bit Waterslide*, collecting a rainbow token lets you spin the Wheel of Misfortune for a bonus.

What are the possible results for the Wheel of Misfortune?

[image: Wheel of Misfortune]